# JavaMail - Getting body text returns null for the first part

Tags: java, null, jakarta-mail, multipart, mime-message

I have written a method that recursively adds the content of the multiple `BodyPart`'s of a `Multipart` message to a string. I don't know why but the first phrase in the string is `null` - why?

Code:

```
protected void dumpPart(Part p, Email email) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        if (p.isMimeType("text/plain"))
        {
            if (!p.getContent().toString().equals(null))
                email.setBody((String)p.getContent());
        }
        else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*"))
        {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();

            for (int x = 0; x < mp.getCount(); x++)
            {
                dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(x), email);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
nullWe did not answer protests to our Order 637 filing...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"p.getContent().toString().equals(null)" is always going to be false.

What does email.setBody do?

Comment: `email.SetBody` adds that part of the body to a string which is later displayed to the user.

Comment: That's not enough information for me to know whether the bug is in that code or not.  Have you tried printing out every string passed to email.setBody to see if anyone is passing it the string "null"?

Comment: It was because I initialised the variable to `null` instead of `""` *IDIOT*